# Unpacked Ruby gems and environment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Do I need to config.gem a gem that's already been unpacked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, no - you don't need to as far as you require it somewhere else by using the require method. In other words, yes, add it to your configuration as well. If you do so, Rails will find and require it for you.

Answer (score 0):

It comes in very handy if you later distribute your app as open source, or someone else comes on to maintain it. You've got one handy list of all the gems your app requires, which versions, etc. Helps to self-document your app.